# How to pass string parameter to c# method using mono embedded?

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I want to pass a `string` parameter to c# method using mono embedded.
Here's c# method:

```
public static void CallMe(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Here's c++ call:

```
PVOID method = mono_class_get_method_from_name(Class, string("CallMe").c_str(), 1);
mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, new void*[1] { (void*)"Hello World!\0" }, NULL);
```

The printed value is either empty string or question marks. How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: Because mono_runtime_invoke has parameter `void**` for parameters

Comment: .NET uses UTF-16 strings. Depending on whether your compiler supports it, prefixing your literal with `u` or `L` may do the trick. (The explicit terminating `\0` is unnecessary.) Also, as written the call has an obvious memory leak (you allocate an array that's never freed).

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert your string in to a *MonoString* using *mono_string_new*.

If you are passing value types you need to pass a pointer (string is a pointer already).

Remember to set *param_count* in *mono_class_get_method_from_name* to the number of parameters in your C# method.

**C++:**

```
void RunMonoMethodWithParams(MonoDomain* domain, PCHAR _namespace, PCHAR _class, PCHAR _method, PCHAR param1)
{
    .
    .
    .
    //Open assembly, get image, class from name...
    .
    .
    .

    PVOID method = mono_class_get_method_from_name(_class, _method, 2);
    
    int param0 = 0xFF;

    //Each index equals 1 parameter
    PVOID args[2];
    args[0] = &param0;
    args[1] = mono_string_new(domain, param1);

    mono_runtime_invoke(method, NULL, args, NULL);
}
```

**C#:**

```
public static int CSharpMethod(int param0, string param1)
{
    ...
}
```